# Creating views of sonar analysis that cuts across multiple modules/packages?

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube

I have a jenkins build that runs sonar analysis on my code base, which is a multi-module maven project. The sonar results allow me to view coverage and issues by drilling down from the project as a whole to the modules, then the packages in those modules, then the classes in those packages.

Is there a way to create different views of the sonar analysis that span different aspects of the project, e.g. "show me the results for packages A,B,C in module M1 and packages X,Y,Z in module M2"?

All this information is (I assume) stored in the database for the project. There may be a plugin that already does this, or maybe I need to write a plugin of my own that queries the database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Views plugin should answer your need: http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/.

If you want an example of how to use it, here is a post on my blog: http://qualilogy.com/en/your-own-quality-model/.
Not recent, but you'll get the idea.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had a quick look at Views, it seems to create views based on projects, rather than based on components of a single project (though I may be wrong here). It's also a commercial plugin and I don't have a budget to play with yet :-(

Comment: I don't believe that you will be able to get a view on any entity without defining it and analyzing because the calculation of the metrics is done during the analysis. In other words, you cannot have an unique project analyzed, and then get data for any subset of this project without analyzing specifically this subset.

Comment: Interesting. One possibility is to create another project that checks out the same source code, but restricts analysis to a small list of inclusions (a set of packages, for example), but I'm not sure if that will work (sonar uses the maven project names for IDs, and there will be multiple uses of the same ID if the same maven project is analysed by multiple sonar projects). Or perhaps the database can be queried directly (outside of sonar) to provide this information?

Comment: There is a webservice that allows to retrieve data from the DB (direct queries are not recommended as the database structure can evolve). However, you would have to develop complex queries, even for simple subset.

Comment: You also have the possibility to declare a single project composed of different modules, which in your case would be your most basic subsets. I don't know if the Views plugin allows to agregate modules, this is something that I want to document for a future post on my blog. Now if it works, you could have any combination of subsets you like and analyze it all with a single analyzis. I know the Views plugin is not free but you can test it for a while and if it has value for your users/company/stakeholders/etc. , then they might allow you to invest on it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've decide to use the `sonar.branch` property to create multiple Sonar projects using the same Maven project. Each Sonar project is provisioned with a different set of inclusions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317178/can-i-analyzing-the-same-maven-project-twice-in-sonar-using-different-sets-of-e/ .