# Can I analyze the same maven project twice in sonar, using different sets of exclusions?

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a multi-module Maven project that is analyzed (within Jenkins) by Sonar. This creates a Sonar project containing metrics for the entire code base of my Maven project. The Sonar project has the same ID as the ID of my Maven project. So if my Maven project is *Foo* (with modules *M1*, *M2*, and *M3*) then I observe that a Sonar project *Foo* is created, and I can see the metrics for components *M1*, *M2*, and *M3*.

I am wondering if I can create another Sonar project that performs analysis on a subset of the Maven project. I can do this with Maven + Cobertura, by specifying a Maven profile that defines the set of packages to be included in (or excluded from) the Cobertura analysis. This allows me to produce a set of Cobertura reports: one for the project as a whole, one for a packages *X*, *Y* and *Z*; etc.

So what I am looking at now is creating a Sonar project called *Bar* that is the result of calculating metrics for the Maven project *Foo*, and that Sonar project will be configured in such a way to include only packages *X*, *Y*, *Z* (which may live in modules *M1*, *M2*, etc). It will kick off as a Jenkins job, checking out Maven project *Foo* and calling the *sonar* post-build action, somehow specifying Sonar project name *Bar* instead of defaulting to *Foo*. Then (I hope) I will have two Sonar projects: *Foo* representing the entire Maven project, and *Bar* representing a subset of that Maven project.

I'm wondering if (a) this is possible, and (b) will it work? I'm not sure if the Sonar database will be corrupted (there will be modules *M1*, *M2*, and *M3* in the Sonar projects *Foo* and *Bar*, these may overwrite the database entries for each other).

**Update 1**

Maybe I can use the `sonar.branch` property when invoking sonar as a post-build action in Jenkins.

e.g.

Jenkins Job One

- SCM: checks out maven project *Foo*
- Build Step: `clean install -DskipTests`
- Post-Build Action: sonar

Jenkins Job Two

- SCM: checks out maven project *Foo*
- Build Step: `clean install -DskipTests`
- Post-Build Action: sonar `-Dsonar.branch=Bar`

I can setup the inclusions/exclusions for the *Bar* branch in Sonar, as necessary. The downside of this approach is that the sonar analysis is run twice on two different branches. It would be much more efficient to run the sonar analysis once and then query the database to narrow the focus as required.

**Update 2**

I'm running into a problem: although I can run a sonar analysis on the branch, the sonar analysis of the original (non-branch) Maven project is failing. The sonar analysis is taking 3 times as long, before it fails with MySQL errors:

`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.`

`The last packet successfully received from the server was 28,962,745 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.`

I don't get any MySQL errors when running a sonar analysis on other Maven projects, however.

Comment: You could try to create a second root for your project or a new parent of your current root and run the second sonar analysis on this one. Since this would only exist for sonar analysis it doesn't seem that nice, but it could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit is correct. Using the `sonar.branch` property creates a different Id, i.e. from the Sonar point of view a different project.

You could include the `sonar.branch` property in your "bar"-profile (of course you need to call the profile in your second job) and thus make sure that your database does not get corrupted.

True, you would need to analyze the project twice, but is much more cleaner that way (and you could later choose to use different rules for your bar profile).

However you would not necessarily need to create two jobs, you can use a Sonar analysis as a build action instead of a post build action.

You might be able to achieve your effect without building twice using the commerical Views plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I experimented with using `sonar.branch` and it seems to do what I wanted. I did try performing a sonar analysis as a jenkins build action (instead of a post-build action) but got some weird class loader errors. Maybe I will investigate this further.

Comment: Running into a problem: although I can run a sonar analysis on the branch, the sonar analysis of the original (non-branch) maven project is failing. And the sonar analysis now takes 3 times as long, before it fails with MySQL errors. I don't get any MySQL errors when running a sonar analysis on other Maven projects. More investigation required ...